# Which of the known variants of Replacement can survive DeExtensionality?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Starting with $\sf ZF$. If we replace the power set axiom by the axiom stating that for any set $A$ there exists a set $x$ such that for every $y \subseteq A$ we have a set $y' \in x$ such that $\forall z \, (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in y')$ (lets denote the latter by $y \equiv y'$).

$\textbf{Powerset*: } \forall A \exists x \forall y \subseteq A \exists y'\in x: y' \equiv y$

Now, lets replace the axiom of Extensionality by the axiom of vigorous violation of Extensionality, or what I'd call as "DeExtensionality", which states that for every set $A$ there does not exist a set having all co-extensional copies of $A$ among its elements, that is:

$\textbf {DeExtensionality: }\forall A \neg \exists B: \forall A' (A' \equiv A \to A' \in B)$

Now call the resulting theory $\sf ZF^*$. It is known that $\sf ZF-Ext.$ is not equi-consistent with $\sf ZF$, a result due to Dana Scott. So, $\sf ZF^*$ won't be equi-consistent with $\sf ZF$ since it has the most flagrant violation of Extensionality.

> Is any of the known variants of Replacement, like Collection and Boundedness, together with Separation, can replace the Replacement axiom scheme in $\sf ZF^*$ in order to render the resulting theory equi-consistent with $\sf ZF$?

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't have a full answer to this question. I'd pose this as a partial answer albeit under slightly different conditions since it assumes a special kind of Choice principle.

If we can have the following kind of choice, then I'd think we can interpret ZFC, if we replace the usual Replacement schema by the Schemas of Separation and Collection.

First we define co-extensionality relation "$\equiv$" as:

$x \equiv y \iff \forall z \, (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)$

Then we state our strengthened choice axiom:

$ \\\begin {align} \textbf {Choice}^*:   \forall X \exists C &\forall \operatorname {nonempty} x \in X:  \\ &(\exists! y : \langle x,y \rangle \in C) \ \land \\& (\forall y: \langle x,y \rangle \in C \to y \in x)\ \land \\ & \exists y \forall x' \in X \, (x'\equiv x \to \langle x',y \rangle \in C )    \end{align} $

Using the function notation, this can be written as:

$\forall X \exists C \forall \operatorname {nonempty} x \in X: \\C(x) \in x \land   \forall x' \in X: x' \equiv x \to C(x')=C(x)$

This is a choice function that would send all nonempty co-extensional elements of a set to a common chosen element from them.

Also, we can state it in alternative manner as any set that is *extensionally* pairwise disjoint admits a choice function. Formally:

$  \forall X: \forall x_1, x_2 \in X (x_1 \not \equiv x_2 \to  \operatorname {empty} x_1 \cap x_2) \to \\ \exists C \forall \operatorname {nonempty} x \in X  \exists  y \, (  C \cap x=\{y\})$

"nonempty" in all the above denotes having at least one element.

Now, we proceed to define an alternative equality relation, lets call it co-equality, as follows:

$x \cong y \iff  \in \restriction \! \operatorname {Tc}(x)  \ \approx \ \in \restriction \! \operatorname {Tc}(y) $

So two sets are co-equal if and only if their transitive closures are isomorphic on membership. That is, the membership graphs on their transitive closures are isomorphic.

Now, we'd label a set as *distinctive* if and only if no distinct elements of it are co-equal.

The plan is to interpret $\sf ZFC$ over the realm $D$ of hereditarily distinctive sets, and with co-equality $\cong$ interpreting equality $=$ and define a co-membership $\in^*$ to interpret membership $\in$, as:

$x \in^* y \iff  \exists z \in y \, (x \cong z)$.

So $(D,\cong, \in^*)$ is our interpreting model. This would satisfy all axioms of $\sf ZFC$.

However, this still doesn't fully answer the question, since this choice principle is not assumed.